# export statement in js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

There is a code sample in [react's  blog](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html).
Which looks like this:

```
export class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {count: props.initialCount};
  }
  tick() {
    this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.tick.bind(this)}>
        Clicks: {this.state.count}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What does the `export` statement mean in this case?
I found [this article on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) but it describes another meaning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is used for [ES6 modules](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html)

In that case it is exporting a class from that module, so you would be able to import it in another module using:

```
import { Counter } from 'path_to_counter';
```

You will need something like [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) to do the module loading if you are using a browser, and possibly a transpiler like [Babel.js](https://babeljs.io/) for the ES6 transpilation